# How to resize two different modal in different size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two  Bootstrap modal. one should be small and one should be large.
when i do

```css
   .modal-content {
    background-clip: padding-box; 
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 600px;
    outline: 0 none; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 1000px;  
    margin-left: -272px;
    margin-top: 115px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

the size of both the modal 600x1000. since both the modal are using the same class `.modal-content`.

**This 1st modal.** `the size of this modal should be 200x200`

```js
function cancel() {
  var $textAndPic = $('<div style=" font-weight: bold; ">Do You Want to Cancel me ?</div>');
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Confirmation',
    message: $textAndPic,
    buttons: [
      {
        label: 'Confirm',
        action: function (dialogRef) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'url
            data: '',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
              alert('Cancelled Successfully');
            },
            error: function (data) {
              alert(' Cancelled Successfully');
            }
          });
          dialogRef.close();
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Deny',
        action: function (dialogRef) {
          dialogRef.close();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

**This is my second modal** the size of this modal should be 600x1000

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="jobId">Filed 1</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Number"> Filed 2</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="organizationName">Filed 3</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="countryCode">Filed 4</th>
            <th class="col-xs-6" data-field="errorMessage"> Filed 5</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use bootstrap classed modal-sm and modal-sm to get different sizes.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

There are already perfect classes for that. Have a look on [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes). So just use `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` as class for different sizes. Default class here is `modal-md`.

If the sizes are not exactly good for you you can go to [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and just download a customized version of bootstrap, just go to modals and you can choose required size yourself.

Comment: in second modal I can specify the class. but how do i specify the class in 1st modal. actually that is an dialog box.. see in first code.

Comment: Well, I don't know the plugin you used there. Why you don't use normal Bootstrap Modal there?